# Is it possible with ant to run just specific android tests or test-packages?

Tags: android, testing, ant, automated-tests, adb

I always prefer ant test command to am instrument to run android tests on my build server, because it's simplier and am instrument doesn't work always.

But so far, I don't know whether if it is possible with ant to run just specific test classes, packages, or suites in order to be more flexible and separate the frequency of run of different test types (like, for example, unit, ui, acceptance, performance etc.).

If there the answer to my question is "no", what else could I do, of course without using am instrument?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a separate Ant target for each type of test, and then make each target conditional on some property.

```
<target name="performance" if="test.performance">
</target>
```

You could then execute the required tests by setting the required properties at build time - e.g. by passing on the Ant command line (`-Dkey=value`) or defining in a properties file which you load in your build file.